# Using Search Ads Attribution API in Adobe AIR

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, unity-game-engine, air, iad

I am trying to get the Search Ads Attribution API code available at http://searchads.apple.com/help/measure-results/#attribution-api working in Adobe AIR Or Unity.

I am copying the code below:

```
    // Check for iOS 10 attribution implementation
if ([[ADClient sharedClient] respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAttributionDetailsWithBlock:)]) { 
NSLog(@"iOS 10 call exists"); 
[[ADClient sharedClient] requestAttributionDetailsWithBlock:^(NSDictionary *attributionDetails, NSError *error) { 
// Look inside of the returned dictionary for all attribution details
NSLog(@"Attribution Dictionary: %@", attributionDetails); 
}];
}

Here’s the response object (version 3.1) from attribution API that contains campaign hierarchy details, bided keyword, download date and click date.

{
"Version3.1" = { 
"iad-attribution" = true;
"iad-campaign-id" = 15292426; 
"iad-campaign-name" = “Light Bright Launch"; 
“iad-conversion-date" = “2016-06-14T17:18:07Z";
"iad-click-date" = “2016-06-14T17:17:00Z";
"iad-group-id" = 15307675; 
"iad-adgroup-name" = "LightRight Launch Group"; 
“iad-keyword” = “light right”; 
}; 
}
```

How do I get this to work in Adobe AIR? Does the milkmangames iAd library support this?

I also referred this link: https://medium.com/@requestlabs/implementing-apple-search-ads-tracking-attribution-6e3966afdf91#.ra6ktweua
I am unable to figure out how to get the Search Ads Attribution api working in Adobe Air OR Unity. Is there any plugin or library that can help?

Thanks,
Nishant

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my blog post on how I was able to set up the [Apple Search Ads Attribution API for tracking installs by keywords](https://kitefaster.com/2016/12/02/how-to-use-the-attribution-api-for-tracking-installs-via-apple-search-ads/) as a good starting place.

I also developed an open source SDK that implements the Attribution API at https://github.com/kitefaster/kitemetrics_iOS.  You can look at the code there and see if that helps.  You could also install the SDK as a CocoaPod or framework and then hook it up to the cloud service at http://kitemetrics.com/.